# My chatbot (lex v2) exceeded intent & utterances quotas and i need more intents. [AWS][LEXV2]

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am creating a large chatbot, the problem is that I have already exceeded the limits that amazon has, I need approximately 1800 intents(it is a large project), and the "[hard limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/quotas.html#quotas-service)" cannot be increased (I already spoke with an amazon agent) , I wanted to know if anyone has experienced this problem and how to solve it (not changing Dialogflow/wattson tools).

I was thinking of creating a "Chatbot Orchestrator" and splitting the chatbot into several parts (experiences) and invoking the corresponding bot and intent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is use [Kendra](https://aws.amazon.com/kendra/) for search the intent, basically i need to activate the fallback intent and use Kendra in a lambda function for the search of the answer.

in [this](https://www.vedereai.com/integrate-amazon-kendra-and-amazon-lex-using-a-search-intent/) document, there is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Kendra, as mentioned already, is an alternative.

However, I would suggest you do a deep dive through your intents to see how many pertain to the same context and can be combined and effectively managed through the use of slots and Lambdas to get the right behaviour.

Another approach would be to use separate bots if you have clean divisions between the intents. Note that your costs here could increase quite substantially as you'd need to invoke all the bots, evaluate the confidence scores and then decide which response to return to the client.